# LibreOffice dictionary and spell checking in other languages? (without Java)

Tags: dictionary, spell-checker, libreoffice

Using LibreOffice (latest version) on OS X, everything in English. However I frequently work with documents in other languages (e.g. German, Dutch, French) and I would like to have spell checking for those languages as well.

I googled around but found tons of links that all either became redundant (since older LibreOffice or OpenOffice versions, I guess) or are no longer available. Nothing I try seems to work.

The only thing that looked hopeful was 'LanguageTool' but this extension seems to require installing Java, which I don't want.

What is the best solution to get foreign language support (as in spell checking / dictionary, not user interface) in LibreOffice **without forcing me to install Java**, and where or how do I go about that exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure for Mac, but checking the package dependencies on Debian, LO uses "hunspell-dictionary, myspell-dictionary" – which in turn both offer a bunch of dictionary backends (a.o. German, Dutch, French with myspell – hunspell seems to lack Dutch). So installing e.g. [MySpell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySpell) should solve it for you (the package is cross-platform according to the linked Wikipedia page).

Answer (score 1):

For french syntax, the best way is to use [Grammalecte](https://dicollecte.org/?download_lo) : it has capacities with grammar and conjugaison (underline words in blue).
To install it, just download the odt file (with a macro).